# Pygame Display Score and Text for my 21 game

Tags: pygame

I have been trying to figure out how to display the pWin and dWin variables in my DISPLAYSURF window in the upper right hand corner and upper left hand corner. How exactly would I do this? Here is my code

```
##21 Card Game 
##Wattel
##2016 Spring

import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *
from random import *
import random
from random import shuffle, randint

Green = (0,200,0)

CARDPOINTS = {'AD': 11,'AH': 11,'AC': 11,'AS': 11,
              'KD': 10,'KH': 10,'KC': 10,'KS': 10,
              'QD': 10,'QH': 10,'QC': 10,'QS': 10, 
              'JD': 10,'JH': 10,'JC': 10,'JS': 10,
              '10D': 10,'10H': 10,'10C': 10,'10S': 10,
              '9D': 9,'9H': 9,'9C': 9,'9S': 9,
              '8D': 8,'8H': 8,'8C': 8,'8S': 8,
              '7D': 7,'7H': 7,'7C': 7,'7S': 7,
              '6D': 6,'6H': 6,'6C': 6,'6S': 6,
              '5D': 5,'5H': 5,'5C': 5,'5S': 5,
              '4D': 4,'4H': 4,'4C': 4,'4S': 4,
              '3D': 3,'3H': 3,'3C': 3,'3S': 3,
              '2D': 2,'2H': 2,'2C': 2,'2S': 2,}

def shuffleDeck():

    List = ['AD','AH','AC','AS',
            'KD','KH','KC','KS',
            'QD','QH','QC','QS', 
            'JD','JH','JC','JS',
            '10D','10H','10C','10S',
            '9D','9H','9C','9S',
            '8D','8H','8C','8S',
            '7D','7H','7C','7S',
            '6D','6H','6C','6S',
            '5D','5H','5C','5S',
            '4D','4H','4C','4S',
            '3D','3H','3C','3S',
            '2D','2H','2C','2S',]
    CardPile = len(List)
    random.shuffle(List)
    return List

def want2play():
    Hit2Play = input(" Hit 'y' to begin your game of 21): ")
    print ("")
    return Hit2Play

def deckCheck(DECK):
    print (DECK)
    print("There are:",len(DECK),"cards in the deck.") 
    if len(DECK) < 20:
        DECK = shuffleDeck() 
        return DECK
    else:
        return DECK

def openingDeal(DECK):
    PHAND = [] 
    DHAND = [] 
    DHANDT = [] 
    PHAND, DECK  = dealOneCard(PHAND, DECK) 
    DHAND, DECK = dealOneCard(DHAND, DECK)
    DHANDT.append(DHAND[0]) 
    PHAND, DECK  = dealOneCard(PHAND, DECK)
    DHAND, DECK = dealOneCard(DHAND, DECK)
    DHANDT.append("back of card")
    PPOINTS = scoreHAND(PHAND)     
    printScores_0(PPOINTS, PHAND, DHANDT)
    return PHAND, DHAND, DHANDT, DECK

def pLoop(PHAND, DHAND, DHANDT, DECK):
    while scoreHAND(PHAND) < 21:
        PlayHH = input('Please hit or hold to continue: ')
        if PlayHH == 'hit':
            dealOneCard(PHAND, DECK)
            printScores_0(scoreHAND(PHAND), PHAND, DHANDT)
        elif PlayHH == 'hold':
            print('Player holds')
            printScores_0(scoreHAND(PHAND), PHAND, DHANDT)
            break
    return PHAND, DHAND, DECK

def dLoop(PHAND, DHAND, DECK):
    printScores_1(scoreHAND(PHAND), scoreHAND(DHAND), PHAND, DHAND)

    if scoreHAND(DHAND) < 18 or scoreHAND(DHAND) < 21 or scoreHAND(DHAND) < scoreHAND(PHAND) or scoreHAND(PHAND) < 22 or scoreHAND(DHAND) < 21:
        dealOneCard(DHAND, DECK)
        printScores_1(scoreHAND(PHAND), scoreHAND(DHAND), PHAND, DHAND)
        return scoreHAND(PHAND), scoreHAND(DHAND), PHAND, DHAND
    else:
        return scoreHAND(PHAND), scoreHAND(DHAND), PHAND, DHAND


def checkScore(pWin, dWin, PPOINTS, DPOINTS):

    if PPOINTS == DPOINTS and PPOINTS < 21:
        dWin += 1
        print (' ')
        print ("Dealer Win")
        return pWin, dWin

    elif PPOINTS > 21:
        dWin += 1
        print(' ')
        print("Dealer Win")
        return pWin, dWin

    elif DPOINTS > 21:
        pWin += 1
        print(' ')
        print("Player Win")
        return pWin, dWin

    elif DPOINTS > PPOINTS and DPOINTS < 22:
        dWin += 1
        print (' ')
        print ("Dealer Win")
        return pWin, dWin

    elif PPOINTS == 21 and DPOINTS == 21:
        print(' ')
        print("Tie")
        return pWin, dWin

    elif PPOINTS > 21 and DPOINTS > 21:
        dWin += 1
        print (' ')
        print ("Dealer Win")
        return pWin, dWin

    else:
        PPOINTS < 22 and DPOINTS > 21
        pWin += 1
        print (' ')
        print ("Player Win")
        return pWin, dWin

def dealOneCard(HAND,DECK):
    theCard = DECK.pop(0)
    HAND.append(theCard) 
    return HAND, DECK

def scoreHAND(HAND):
    points = addScore(HAND) 
    aceCount=0
    if points > 21:
        aceCount += HAND.count('AS')
        aceCount += HAND.count('AH')
        aceCount += HAND.count('AC')
        aceCount += HAND.count('AD')
        while points > 21 and aceCount > 0:
            points -= 10
            aceCount -= 1
        return points
    else:
        return points

def addScore(HAND):
    tempScore = 0
    for i in HAND:
        tempScore += CARDPOINTS[i]
    return tempScore 

def printScores_0(POINTS, HAND, HAND1):
    print("Player's cards: ", HAND, "Player's hand score: ", POINTS)
    print("Dealer's cards: ", HAND1)

def printScores_1(PPOINTS, DPOINTS, PHAND, DHAND):
    print("Player's cards: ", PHAND, "Player's hand score: ", PPOINTS)
    print("Dealer's cards: ", DHAND, "Dealer's hand score: ", DPOINTS)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    gamex,gamey=(500,500)
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((gamex,gamey))
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(Green)
    pygame.display.update()

    DECK = shuffleDeck()
    pWin = 0
    dWin = 0    

    while True:
        Hit2Play = want2play()
        if Hit2Play == 'y':
            DECK = deckCheck(DECK)
            PHAND, DHAND, DHANDT, DECK = openingDeal(DECK)
            PHAND, DHAND, DECK = pLoop(PHAND, DHAND, DHANDT, DECK)
            PPOINTS, DPOINTS, PHAND, DHAND = dLoop(PHAND, DHAND, DECK)
            pWin, dWin = checkScore(pWin, dWin, PPOINTS, DPOINTS)
            print("")
            print("Player's Wins:", pWin, "Dealer's Wins:",dWin)
            print("")

        else:
            print("Player's Wins:", pWin, "Dealer's Wins:",dWin)

            break

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can see no game loop going on whatsoever. You created the surface and updated it only once. A valid game loop would look something like this:

```
while True:
    # Event handling
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    # Game logic

    # Rendering
    DISPLAYSURF.fill((0, 0, 0,)) # Filling the screen with black to clear previous frame
    pWin_textObj = font.render(str(pWin), True, pWin_textColor)
    dWin_textObj = font.render(str(dWin), True, dWin_textColor)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(pWin_textObj, (0, 0)) # Place pWin text in upper left corner
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(dWin_textObj, (500-dWin_textObj.get_width(), 0)) # Place pWin text in upper right corner

    pygame.display.update()
```

`pWin_textColor` and `dWin_textColor` are both rgb tuples such as (0, 0, 0) or (144, 100, 255).

However, from what I can see of your code, your game is based on console input for gameplay, and the pygame display is only used for displaying the score(?). Because of the required game loop, the console becomes unusable. To be able to implement your idea of both console and pygame window, you're going to have to do some research on threading or multiprocessing. Best of luck.